# Collapsing rows based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

**Input:**

```
Restaurant     IP_Id  IP_Time                 S_Code
McDonalds      NaN    2021-03-28 03:01:05     4
McDonalds      NaN    2021-03-28 03:01:05     5
McDonalds      NaN    2021-03-28 03:01:05     6
McDonalds      101    2021-03-28 03:01:05     4
McDonalds      101    2021-03-28 03:01:05     5
Wendys         101    2021-03-28 03:01:05     4
Wendys         101    2021-03-28 03:01:05     4
```

I want to transform the dataframe to the following. For every instance where the `IP_Id` is the same for a specific restaurant at a specific time, I want to collapse the row and include a comma separated value for the `S_Code`.

**Output:**

```
Restaurant     IP_Id  IP_Time                 S_Code
McDonalds      NaN    2021-03-28 03:01:05     4
McDonalds      NaN    2021-03-28 03:01:05     5
McDonalds      NaN    2021-03-28 03:01:05     6
McDonalds      101    2021-03-28 03:01:05     4, 5
Wendys         101    2021-03-28 03:01:05     4
```

I've tried grouping by Restaurant, IP_Id, and IP_Time, but it moves the records with Nan as the IP_Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite simple. You'll need a special condition to separate the NaNs into their own groups, which you can generate with a combination of `shift` and `cumsum`, and then call `agg('unique')`:

```
g = df.groupby([df['IP_Id'].ne(df['IP_Id'].shift(1)).cumsum(), df['Restaurant'], df['IP_Time']])
df = g['S_Code'].agg('unique').str.join(', ').reset_index().assign(IP_Id=g['IP_Id'].first().reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   IP_Id Restaurant             IP_Time S_Code
0    NaN  McDonalds 2021-03-28 03:01:05      4
1    NaN  McDonalds 2021-03-28 03:01:05      5
2    NaN  McDonalds 2021-03-28 03:01:05      6
3  101.0  McDonalds 2021-03-28 03:01:05   4, 5
4  101.0     Wendys 2021-03-28 03:01:05      4
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I'm running this on a larger dataset however and seems that the performance is quite slow. Is this because of the multiple groupings?

Comment: Also just noticed that the IP_Id is no longer the same as prior.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's slow. I think you should trim off everything off of the code and incrementally add it back on, running the resulting code each time, to see what affects the speed the most.

Comment: I like your solution but how can i keep the original IP_Ids?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that change of `IP_Id` :) Check the answer now.